# Registry > App Paths: Modify a string so that app could open a particular file?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-registry, path, regedit

Is it possible to modify a string in `Registry > App Paths` in such a way that it will not only open an application but also a particular file in it? Similar to the target box in shortcuts (windows .lnk files).

And if it is possible then I would like to ask what would be the correct format of the string? Because I tried everything and nothing worked.

In my particular case, the key is called `paint.exe` and the string/path is `C:\Program Files\paint.net\PaintDotNet.exe`
And I would like to add this `C:\Program Files\paint.net\MyTemplate.png` somehow, so when the application starts it will automatically open the file `MyTemplate.png`.

Answer (score 1):

Try `"C:\Program Files\paint.net\PaintDotNet.exe" "C:\Program Files\paint.net\MyTemplate.png"` (the image file is an argument of the executable)

Comment: Did you verify this works?

Comment: No, I haven't, but this link shows that it should work: https://forums.getpaint.net/topic/29030-command-line-switches/?do=findComment&comment=412965

Comment: @iTechieGamer I had already tried that. It didn't work!